# How can I prevent linking to a specific function in a DLL, in order to maintain compatibility with an older version of that DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, linker

###### The short version of the question:

Is it possible for me to instruct Microsoft's command line C++ compiler to link against a dynamic library and tell the linker not to link against one specific function in that DLL, given the function's name (mangled or unmangled) or perhaps its ordinal, in order to preserve compatibility with earlier versions of the library's DLL that don't include that function?

###### The long explanation:

I'm developing a DLL that's a plug-in for Autodesk Maya 2020. This DLL needs to link against one of Maya 2020's dynamic libraries named OpenMayaUI.

Normally plug-ins built for one major version of Maya (such as 2020) are supposed to be binary compatible with any other minor versions of that major version. For example, a plug-in built using Maya 2020.4 should still load in Maya 2020.0.

However, Autodesk messed this up and introduced a single new function in Maya 2020.3's version of OpenMayaUI.dll that's not present in Maya 2020.0, Maya 2020.1, or Maya 2020.2. Consequently, if I build my plug-in so that it's linking to the version of OpenMayaUI.lib that comes from Maya 2020.3 or 2020.4, trying to load the plug-in in an earlier version of Maya 2020 will fail with the error "the specified procedure cannot be found". (And this is correct, the procedure isn't provided in the earlier versions of OpenMayaUI.dll.) However, linking against Maya 2020.0's version of OpenMayaUI.lib will produce a DLL that can be loaded by any version of Maya 2020.

Unfortunately, the script that builds my plug-in needs to be able to be run on a system with any version of Maya 2020 installed, including 2020.3 and 2020.4. But I need the builds it generates to be compatible with Maya 2020.0 nonetheless.

So, is it possible for me to link against the Maya 2020.4 version of OpenMayaUI.lib, but somehow tell the linker to avoid linking to the specific function in that dynamic library that's not present in the Maya 2020.0 version of OpenMayaUI? In this case I know the exact name of the function, both mangled and unmangled, and I know its ordinal in both the 2020.0 and 2020.4 versions of OpenMayaUI.dll.

I'm building the plug-in using Microsoft's command line C++ compiler included with Visual Studio 2019.

*Edit with additional information:* The offending function is a virtual member function in one of Maya's C++ classes, so even though I'm not calling it, my DLL still gets linked against it.

Comment: welcome to dll hell -  can you perhaps load the function dynamically  in your code rather than via the linker?

Comment: Use dynamic linking [`GetProcAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) __just__ for the new function and link against the older export library for all the existing functions.  If the `GetProcAddress` fails you also know that the use only has the older DLL installed and can program round the problem.

Comment: @NeilButterworth While that is possible, it is unfortunately that's not really practical given the number of functions from OpenMayaUI that I'm already linking against and the effort involved.

Comment: @RichardCritten (Ignore my previous inaccurate and now deleted comment). I'm not explicitly using the offending function in my code, though it's a member function of a class that I am making use of, and therefore seems to be automatically linked against.

Comment: Expanding on what Richard said, another option is to link to the newer export library normally, but tell the linker that the DLL is to be **delay loaded**. That way, all of the DLL functions are loaded dynamically at runtime only when called, so you can avoid calling the newer function if it is missing in an older DLL. Or, you can use a delay-load hook to redirect a missing function to another function of the app's choosing (for instance, to a stub function that reports `ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`, or implements equivalent functionality as the missing function, or calls an older function, etc).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unless I misunderstand how it works, delay loading a DLL means the DLL itself will not load until a function in it is called. But wouldn't that just put off the problem? The DLL still won't load due to a missing function.

Comment: @BriBri delay-loaded functions are not referred to in the caller's IMPORTS table, so the called DLL won't fail to load if a linked function is missing. Delay-loading allows the caller to have the simplicity of static linking with the flexibility of `LoadLibrary`+`GetProcAddress` without having to call them explicitly in code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are correct, using delay loading fixes the issue, at least in my case. If you submit it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @BriBri I have posted an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible for me to link against the Maya 2020.4 version of OpenMayaUI.lib, but somehow tell the linker to avoid linking to the specific function in that dynamic library that's not present in the Maya 2020.0 version of OpenMayaUI?

Yes. Tell the linker that `OpenMayaUI.dll` is to be **delay loaded**.

[Linker support for delay-loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=msvc-170)

That way, every function that your code calls from that DLL will not be linked to *statically* in your plugin's IMPORTS table, but rather will be loaded at runtime via `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` the first time they are called. This way, your plugin has the opportunity to verify the DLL's version before calling the missing function.